# Are these locked memory accesses equivalent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, atomic

```
void f1(volatile int* ptr, int value)
{
    *ptr = value;
    lock or DWORD PTR [rsp], 0; // MemoryBarrier()
}


void f2(volatile int* ptr, int value)
{
    xchg DWORD PTR [ptr], value; // InterlockedExchange(ptr, value);
}
```

Equivalent in terms of semantics. Apparently `xchg` is locked whether or not the `lock` prefix is specified or not.

Edit: I'm using VS2010 currently but will probably port to VS2012 where I believe the compiler semantics regarding `volatile` have changed again.

Comment: Please improve the title so that the article will be useful to future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly yes. The `lock or` on the first case makes sure that the data has been updated before any other CPU can read any more memory, in the second case, the `xchg` instruction has an implicit lock, so all other processor (cores) will have to "release" their value of *ptr before your processor can update the value.